# Memory error in C without compiler error

Tags: c, memory

I do not understand why i am getting a memory error here. The compiler does not return any errors or warnings in this code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Aufruf: %s <anzahl> <bundesland>\n", argv[0]);
        printf("Beispiel: %s 100 Bayern\n", argv[0]);
        printf("Klein-/Großschreibung beachten!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int anzahl = atoi(argv[1]);
    char *bundesland = argv[2];

    // Statisch allokierter Speicher
    char staedte[MAX_LAENGE_ARR][MAX_LAENGE_STR];
    char laender[MAX_LAENGE_ARR][MAX_LAENGE_STR];
    int bewohner[MAX_LAENGE_ARR];

    int len = read_file("staedte.csv", staedte, laender, bewohner);
    char** result;
    int storage=0;
    int result_storage=0;

        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if((strcmp(bundesland, laender[i]) == 0) && (bewohner[i] >= anzahl)){
            storage++;
        }
    }
    result = (char**) malloc(storage);
    for (int j = 0; j < storage; j++){
        result[j] = (char*) malloc(100);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if((strcmp(bundesland, laender[i]) == 0) && (bewohner[i] >= anzahl)){
            sprintf(result[result_storage], "Die Stadt %s hat %d Einwohner", staedte[i], bewohner[i]);
            result_storage++;
        }
    }
    len = storage;
    write_file(result, len);
    for(int p = 0; p < storage ; p++={
        free(result[p]);
    }
    free(result);
    return(0);
}
```

The results are saved in a .txt file. If this file is opened in notepad++ while starting the program, notepad++ wants to reload the file and crashes. The functions read_file and write_file are in the file input.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "input3.h"

int MAX_LAENGE_STR = 255;
int MAX_LAENGE_ARR = 100;

void write_file(char *result[], int len) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("resultat.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL){
        perror("resultat.txt");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        fprintf(fp, "%s\n", result[i]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

int read_file(char *dateiname, char laender[][MAX_LAENGE_STR], char staedte[][MAX_LAENGE_STR], int bewohner []) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(dateiname, "r");

    if (fp == NULL){
        perror(dateiname);
        exit(1);
    }

    char stadt[MAX_LAENGE_STR];
    char land[MAX_LAENGE_STR];
    int anzahl;
    int i = 0;
    int len;

    while(fscanf(fp, "\"%[^\"]\";\"%[^\"]\";%d\n", land, stadt, &anzahl) != EOF)
    {
        if (i >= MAX_LAENGE_ARR) {
            printf("ERROR: Die Datei ist größer als erwartet!");
            return i;
        }
        len = strlen(land) + 1;
        strncpy(laender[i], land, len-1);
        laender[i][len-1] = '\0';

        len = strlen(stadt) + 1;
        strncpy(staedte[i], stadt, len-1);
        staedte[i][len-1] = '\0';

        bewohner[i] = anzahl;
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return i;
}
```

I am not able to change anything in the input.c file and the 'staedte.csv' file is strucktured like this:

```
"Berlin";"Berlin";3460725
"Hamburg";"Hamburg";1786448
"München";"Bayern";1353186
"Köln";"Nordrhein-Westfalen";1007119
"Frankfurt am Main";"Hessen";679664
"Stuttgart";"Baden-Württemberg";606588
"Düsseldorf";"Nordrhein-Westfalen";588735
"Dortmund";"Nordrhein-Westfalen";580444
"Essen";"Nordrhein-Westfalen";574635
"Bremen";"Bremen";547340
```

Comment: What does notepad++ have to do with your program?

Comment: 'I do not understand why i am getting a memory error here. The compiler does not return any errors or warnings in this code' - lol, that can happen, believe it or not.

Comment: Just because code compiles without errors doesn't mean the code is correct, or that it will run without errors. The compiler has no idea what your program is really up to. Compiling without errors is just the first step of many to code correctness. However, if you turn on warnings, sometimes you can catch more potential errors before hand if you address the warnings.

Comment: How large are `MAX_LAENGE_ARR` and `MAX_LAENGE_STR`? You have to use a debugger to narrow down where the memory error occurs for us. What type of memory error? Crash?

Comment: It would be better to check `while(fscanf(...) == 3)` than your `while(fscanf(...) != EOF)` and then you'll catch file content errors (which might cause problems) as well as `EOF`

Comment: The point is that the program does not crash at all on my system. But reloading the txt file results in a crash for my editor what should not happen at all.
And also i am not sure how to debug for a memory error

Comment: Gee, it's almost as if `sizeof(char*) != 1` on your system.

Comment: overlooking the fact that the posted code is missing several necessary #include statements for header files,  the compiler raises several error messages.   Here is the target of one of the error messages:  `for(int p = 0; p < storage ; p++={`  where there is a '=' instead of the required ')'

Comment: regarding your text editor `notepad`:   every time you run the program, a NEW file is created/the old file is destroyed.  The editor is trying to edit the old file, which suddenly doesn't exist.

Comment: in `read-file()` the format string for the call to fscanf() should have length modifiers of 1 less than the max length of the receiving fields to avoid buffer overflows.

Comment: in `read_file()`, this kind of line: `strncpy(laender[i], land, len-1);` is not necessarily correct.   it should be: `strncpy(laender[i], land, MAX_LAENGE_STR);`   then the calls to `strlen()`, the variable `len` and the related length twiddling can be eliminated.

Comment: the input.c file needs a header file (preferably of the same root name) and that header file needs to be #include'd in the file that contains the main() function,

Comment: @EOF, I would sincerely hope that `sizeof(char*)` is either 4 or 8.

Comment: these variable declarations in input.c are unknown in the file that contains the main() function.   strongly suggest removing those two lines and placing two #define statements in the input.h file (which both of the .c files should #include)  then you can be sure that all the files have the same idea about the sizing of the arrays

Comment: if you are not allowed to modify the input.c file, then suggest a discussion with your instructor about the severe/disastrous problems with that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding these lines:

```
result = (char**) malloc(storage);
for (int j = 0; j < storage; j++)
{
    result[j] = (char*) malloc(100);
}
```

do not cast the returned value from malloc() because that returned value is a `void *` type, so can be assigned to any pointer variable and just clutters the code resulting in a headache when debugging or performing maintenance.

always check (!=NULL) the returned value from every call to malloc() to assure the operation was successful.

this line:

```
result = (char**) malloc(storage);
```

is allocating 'storage' bytes, it should be allocating 'storage*sizeof(result)' bytes.

(note: sizeof(result) is the same as sizeof(char**)

So the code is not allocating nearly enough storage.  This results in this line:

```
result[j] = (char*) malloc(100);
```

soon writing past the end of the allocated storage, which corrupts the heap structure, which results in undefined behaviour and can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: Allocating 'storage*sizeof(result)' bytes did solve the problem, thank you very much!